# Change try-catch hilighting color

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I debug in visual studio into a try catch it will highlight the entire try catch block as shown below using the default color scheme.

[image: Picture of highlighted try catch color]

This is annoying when using a black background color scheme like son of obsidian.

How do I change it?

I tried most of the options in Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors [Text Editor]. Can I find it there or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools | Options | Fonts And Colors | Read-Only Region